# Unclear division operation

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm having trouble understanding what the following code means exactly:

```
1:5/3:5
```

this, as I understand, translates to

```
1.0e+00    2.0e+00    3.0e+00    4.0e+00    5.0e+00 / 3.0e+00    4.0e+00    5.0e+00
```

the answer is:

```
1.0e+00    2.6e+00    4.3e+00
```

My question is: what exactly is being done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the following code

```
a:b:c
```

It will print values between a and c with a step of b.

So, if a=1; b=5/3; c=5, it will print

> 1
>   1+1*5/3
>   1+2*5/3
>   ...

as long as the value is inferior or equal to 5

Answer (score 3):

The best way to understand it is by looking at MATLAB's [operator precedence](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html).

Of interest here is:

> 5. Multiplication `(.*)`, right division `(./)`, left division `(.\)`, matrix multiplication `(*)`, matrix right division `(/)`, matrix left
>      division `(\)`
>
> ...
>
> 7. Colon operator `(:)`

So `5/3` is evaluated before the [`colon` operation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and used as the increment. If we were to do `(1:5)/(3:5)`, then the behavior would be as you guessed above. And you would get an error because the dimensions are not compatible for right matrix division.